# Odd thing with javascript "undefined"

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following simple Javascript code.

```
var input = [
    'one',
    'two'
];

for(var i in input){
    if(typeof input[i+1] == undefined){
        console.log("i is the last index");
    }
}
```

I don't know if I did something wrong but the `console.log()` part never executes. Which means it never enters the `if` condition while clearly the index beyond the last index is undefined.

You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alihaideri/vRTsE/).

Please explain..

Comment: `typeof` returns a string. `undefined` is... undefined.

Comment: [Do not use `for in`-enumerations on arrays!!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: Yet another example of why people shouldn't use `typeof foo === "undefined"` to check for the `undefined` value. It causes far more bugs than it "solves". Just keep it simple and test for `input[i+1] == undefined`, and ignore the FUD people spread. They've usually not really thought things through.

Comment: ...anyway, your test for the last index can fail since a defined index can have the `undefined` value. I really don't know why you're using `for-in` like this, but to test for the last index, you should be comparing the `i+1` to `input.length`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if(typeof input[i+1] === 'undefined') { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
if(typeof input[i+1] == undefined){
```

Should be:

```
if(input[i+1] === undefined){
```

(no need to use `typeof`)

Comment: Ok, the downvotes mean I'm being dumb but can someone explain why? This works correctly (I've double-checked it in Chrome). Is it simply poor style?

Comment: +1 You are right, i think the dumbest ones have down-voted this post

Comment: Sorry, was sure you wrote `if (typeof input[i+1] === undefined)` my mistake. Took the liberty too edit your post so I can undo my mistake.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Thanks. I probably should have made it clearer to start with

Comment: I made the same mistake as ShadowWizard. Have removed my downvote

Answer (score 3):

Undefined should be a string, `"undefined"`, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/vRTsE/1/

Comment: @asim-ishaq It works fine for me in Chrome.. from a console, from the fiddle I linked above, and even a quick page on my local server.. Does the fiddle not work in Chrome for you? I'd be curious to know why..

Answer (score 1):

That is because the typeof operator returns an string. You need to compare with a string "undefined" like so:

```
var input = [
    'one',
    'two'
];

for(var i in input){
    if(typeof input[i+1] == "undefined"){
        console.log("i is last");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` returns a string. You're comparing it to the `undefined` value.

Use

```
if(typeof input[i+1] === "undefined"){
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript `typeof` operator always returns string, so you should compare against `'undefined'` like this:

```
if(typeof input[i+1] === 'undefined')
```

Here is an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/V7EJZ/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the type of `i` is string, so to make the code work properly you need to cast it to integer:

```
for(var i in input){
    if(typeof input[parseInt(i, 10) + 1] === "undefined") {
        console.log(i + " is the last index");
    }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRTsE/2/).